# Write list of lists to excel file using xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have a list of lists like:

```
[
[u'email', u'salutation', u'firstname', u'lastname', u'remarks', None, None, None, None, None],
[u'harry@harrypotter.com', u'Mr', u'Daniel', u'Radcliffe', u'expecto patronum', None, None, None, None, None],
[u'snape@harrypotter.com', u'Mr', u'Severus', u'Snape', u'Always', None, None, None, None, None],
]
```

I want to insert this to an excel file. It is possible to do so one by one by writing each element.

```
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

row = 0
for l in listdata:
    col = 0
    for e in l:
        if e:
          sheet1.write(row, col, e)
        col+=1
    row+=1
```

But this method does not look very efficient as the each element of the entire list has to be traversed. Is there a more efficient method to do the same in python with `xlwt`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: Fixed error in benchmark code.

You can shorten things a bit to make them more pythonic:

```
for i, l in enumerate(listdata):
    for j, col in enumerate(l):
        sheet.write(i, j, col)
```

But as far as I know there is no easy method to write to as there is with `csv.reader`.

---

PS: In your supplied code, you never increment `row` or `col`, so you overwrite the cell at `(0,0)` every iteration of the nested for loop. Careful! Using `enumerate` will fix that.

---

### Benchmarks

As it turns out, `join`ing each row together with a comma and writing it is roughly 3 times faster than using enumerate once.

Here's some test code:

```
import xlwt
import timeit


def wrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

def excel_writer():
    xldoc = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    rows = [[str(y) for y in xrange(100)] for x in xrange(10000)]
    fn1 = wrapper(cell_writer, rows, sheet1)
    fn2 = wrapper(row_writer, rows, sheet1)
    print timeit.timeit(fn1, number=10)/10 
    print timeit.timeit(fn2, number=10)/10 
    xldoc.save('myexcel.xls')


def cell_writer(rows, sheet):
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(i, j, col)

def row_writer(rows, sheet):
    rows = [', '.join(row) for row in rows]
    for i, strrow in enumerate(rows):
        sheet.write(i, 0, strrow)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    excel_writer()
```

with `number = 1` (divided by 1 of course):

> cell_writer: `15.2915050441`
>
> **row_writer**: `0.205128928987`

with `number = 10`:

> cell_writer: `17.3386430596`
>
> **row_writer**: `0.204951626882`

I attribute the big time difference to the increased speed of `join` over writing to excel. The biggest bottleneck in terms of speed, of course, the excel writing.

However, be aware that the time it takes to split the cells apart in excel may outweigh the time saved with the `row_writer` approach. It may also inconvenience the end user; exercise judgement!

Comment: Oh thanks, corrected the increment thing. enumerate is helpful, does't help speedup though. I was thinking if it is possible to join all elements of the list and write them to the excel at once as a string to make it faster. Don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: @pramttl Well, the problem is you would have to manually split them in into columns in excel after. So while it may speed things up in python, does that outweigh the time it takes to open excel and split into columns? I think it depends on the application.

Comment: @pramttl I'm writing up a little benchmark test. Hang on.

Comment: Oh great, would be interesting to see the results.

Comment: @pramttl Fixed the results a bit and used a list comp for accuracy. It's now good.

Comment: It is interesting to see the benchmark results, but as you mentioned. The row_writer does not write to the excel file the way it is desired (ie. each element in the row list should take one cell) But, the results are interesting to know. I would have given this answer another upvote if I could.

Comment: @pramttl Does it answer your question? I'm digging through the source cod but honestly, I don't think there's a way to write an entire row at once; regardless, it would be just as slow as writing each cell individually because `xlwt` would still have to access each cell.

Comment: It is a very good answer, but I am still hoping if someone knows how to write to list of lists to excel each cell having a single value in an efficient manner. But I am afraid maybe that is not possible yet with xlwt. :/

Comment: @pramttl you might want to take a look at another module, like [`pyxl`](http://pythonhosted.org//openpyxl/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook). At this point it's up to you to do that research - I'm going to have to put money on that fact that the only way `xlwt` writes is to access each cell individually.