# How to write nested list to excel in python?

Tags: python

I have a nested list like:

```
lst = [['Fruit'], [1,2,3,4], [{'name':'banana', 'count': 3, 'color':'red'}, {'name':'apple', 'count': 12, 'color':'green'}]]
```

and I want to write this list to an excel file (.xlsx). My expected result is:

[image]

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307961/14362977) I used:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('lst.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

lst = [['Fruit'], [1,2,3,4], [{'name':'banana', 'count': 3, 'color':'red'}, {'name':'apple', 'count': 12, 'color':'green'}]]
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    for j, col in enumerate(l):
        worksheet.write(i, j, col)
        
workbook.close()
```

but it gives an error: `TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'dict'> in write()`

Comment: did you try `write(i, j, str(col))`?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters It fixes the given error, but write to file in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with:

```
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    worksheet.write(0, i, ','.join([str(elem) for elem in lst[i]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the elements into string before writing into the Excel sheet

```
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    for j, col in enumerate(l):
        worksheet.write(i, j, str(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way to do so would be to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([lst]).to_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem Specification

> *You're using `Nested Loop` for entering your data into **Excel File**, So, you need to care about your data algorithm of what you're entering in case of `index()`*

#### Processing The code

- *Let’s see how to create and write to an excel-sheet using Python. I will use your **excel package** not to make any confusion.*

***Algorithm***

- You need To care about the *indexing position* of your data, so what we gonna do is explain how the data is entered;
- we want it to look like this:

```
i j lista
0 0 fruit
0 1 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
0 2 {'name': 'banana', 'count': 3}
```

*In python, It should looks like this,*

```py
# I've a List of lists called `lista`:-
lista = [['Fruit'], [(1,2,3,4)], [{'name':'banana', 'count': 3, 'color':'red'}, {'name':'apple', 'count': 12, 'color':'green'}]

# By using `Nested Loop`, we can specify the entrance of the data of `lista`
for i in range(1):    # Specify any range you want
    for j in range(0, len(lista)):
        print(i, j, list[j][i])
```

#### The code:

```py
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('lst.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# First, to add the sec `index`, you need to add it into a `tuple`

lst = [['Fruit'], [(1,2,3,4]), [{'name':'banana', 'count': 3, 'color':'red'}, {'name':'apple', 'count': 12, 'color':'green'}]]

for i in range(1):    # Specify any range you want
    for j in range(0, len(lista)):
        worksheet.write(i, j, lista[j][i])
     
workbook.close()
```

***OUTPUT***
[image]